# Find text between 2 tags with malformed XML and including nested tags

Tags: php, xml, parsing, xml-parsing, html-parsing

Is there any easy way to find text between 2 tags with malformed XML and ignoring nesting?

Given this content:

```
<div>
    Some content 1
    </
    <some:tag>
        Section 1
    </some:tag>
    <b>Some content 2
    <some:tag>
        Section 2
        <some:tag>
            Section 3
        </some:tag>
    </some:tag>
    Some content 3
    </p>
</div>
```

*Note: it is purposefully malformed. I can't/don't want to use a proper HTML/XML parser as my content is not properly formed, or in some cases not even XML. And likewise I can't/don't want to run a tidy on it as its not always HTML/XML.*

So I need to find the text between `<some:tag>` and `</some:tag>`, including nested tags.

The content above would result in:

```
array (size=2)

  0 => string '<some:tag>
            Section 1
        </some:tag>' (length=52)

  1 => string '<some:tag>
            Section 2
            <some:tag>
                Section 3
            </some:tag>
        </some:tag>' (length=125)
```

The obligatory what have you tried:

I have tried using strpos/substr to pull out the matches, but I am getting a bit lost on the logic:

```
function findSomeTag($str) {
    $result = [];
    $startTag = "<some:tag>";
    $endTag = "</some:tag>";
    $offset = 0;
    $start = strpos($str, $startTag, $offset);
    while ($start !== false) {
        $nextStart = strpos($str, $startTag, $start + 1);
        $nextEnd = strpos($str, $endTag, $start + 1);
        if ($nextStart === false || $nextEnd < $nextStart) {
            $result[] = substr($str, $start, $nextEnd - $start + strlen($endTag));
        }
        $start = $nextStart;
    }
    return $result;
}
```

*(Note: the above function totally does not work, and will probably infinite loop.)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike my other answer, this version will read tags with nested tags:

```
$text = "
<div>
    Some content 1
    </
    <some:tag>
        Section 1
    </some:tag>
    <b>Some content 2
    <some:tag>
        Section 2
        <some:tag>
            Section 3
        </some:tag>
    </some:tag>
    Some content 3
    </p>
</div>
";

$parser = new Parser( new TextReader($text) );
$found = $parser->findTags("<some:tag>", "</some:tag>");

class TextReader {
    private $idx = 0;
    private $reading;
    private $lastIdx;

    public function __construct($reading) {
        $this->reading = $reading;
        $this->lastIdx = strlen($reading) - 1;
    }

    public function hasMore() {
        return $this->idx < $this->lastIdx;
    }

    public function nextChar() {
        if( !$this->hasMore() ) return null;

        return $this->reading[$this->idx++];
    }

    public function rewind($howFar) {
        $this->idx -= $howFar;
        if( $this->idx < 0 ) $this->idx = 0;
    }
}


class Parser {
    private $TextReader;

    public function __construct($TextReader) {
        $this->TextReader = $TextReader;
    }

    public function findTags($startTagName, $endTagName) {
        $found = array();

        while( ($next = $this->findNextTag($startTagName, $endTagName)) != null ) {
            $found[] = $next;
        }

        return $found;
    }

    public function findNextTag($startTagName, $endTagName) {
        // find the start of our first tag
        $junk = $this->readForTag($startTagName);
        if( $junk == null ) return null; // didn't find another tag

        $nests = 0;
        $started = false;

        $startLength = strlen($startTagName);
        $endLength = strlen($endTagName);

        $readSoFar = "";

        while($this->TextReader->hasMore()) {
            // found a start tag
            if( substr( $readSoFar, $readSoFarLength - $startLength ) == $startTagName ) {
                $started = true;
                $nests++;
            }

            // found an end tag
            if( substr( $readSoFar, $readSoFarLength - $endLength ) == $endTagName ) $nests--;

            $readSoFar .= $this->TextReader->nextChar();

            // if we've started, and we found as many starts as ends
            if( $started && $nests == 0 ) return $readSoFar;
        }

        return null;
    }

    /*
     * read the Text Reader until you find a certain tag, and
     * return what you read before finding the tag, including the tag itself
     *
     * Text Reader will be rewound to the beginning of the tag
     */
    private function readForTag($tagName) {
        $readSoFar = "";

        $tagNameLength = strlen($tagName);

        while($this->TextReader->hasMore()) {
            // if the last few characters read are the tag
            if( substr( $readSoFar, strlen($readSoFar) - $tagNameLength ) == $tagName ) {
                // rewind
                $this->TextReader->rewind($tagNameLength);

                // return what we've read
                return $readSoFar;
            }

            $readSoFar .= $this->TextReader->nextChar();
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems to work although I ended up with this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23796360/268074

Answer (score 1):

To include nested tags you could count the number of currently opened tags.

So while `$nextEnd > $nextStart` increment `$counter`, and only add a new result when you `$nextEnd < $nextStart && $counter == 1` (you have one open tag). If `$nextEnd < $nextStart && $counter < 1` decrement `$counter`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to do any parsing is to use something like a state machine.  Basically you define a certain set of states and the conditions by which you leave those states and enter other states.

Let's assume you have your text in some kind of text reader that can give you the next character and move a pointer forward, and also rewind the pointer a certain number of characters.

Then you could create a state machine kinda like this (it turned out to be a simple state machine, with only one state that basically cycled within itself):

```
class StateMachine {
    private $TextReader;

    public function __construct($TextReader) {
        $this->TextReader = $TextReader;
    }

    public function getTagContents($startTagName, $endTagName) {
        $tagsFound = array();

        // read until we get to the start of a tag
        while( $this->stateReadForTag($startTagName) != null ) {
            // now read until we find the end
            $contents = $this->stateReadForTag($endTagName);

            // didn't find the end
            if( $contents == null ) break;

            $tagsFound[] = $contents;
        }

        return $tagsFound;
    }

    /*
     * read the Text Reader until you find a certain tag, and
     * return what you read before finding the tag, including the tag itself
     *
     * Text Reader will be rewound to the beginning of the tag
     */
    private function stateReadForTag($tagName) {
        $readSoFar = "";

        $tagNameLength = strlen($tagName);

        while($this->TextReader->hasMore()) {
            // if the last few characters read are the tag
            if( substr( $readSoFar, strlen($readSoFar) - $tagNameLength ) == $tagName ) {
                // rewind
                $this->TextReader->rewind($tagNameLength);

                // return what we've read
                return $readSoFar;
            }

            $readSoFar .= $this->TextReader->nextChar();
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Then call it like this:

```
$found = $myStateMachine->getTagContents("<some:tag>", "</some:tag>");
```

The TextReader could look like this:

```
class TextReader {
    private $idx = 0;
    private $reading;
    private $lastIdx;

    public function __construct($reading) {
        $this->reading = $reading;
        $this->lastIdx = strlen($reading) - 1;
    }

    public function hasMore() {
        return $this->idx < $this->lastIdx;
    }

    public function nextChar() {
        if( !$this->hasMore() ) return null;

        return $this->reading[$this->idx++];
    }

    public function rewind($howFar) {
        $this->idx -= $howFar;
        if( $this->idx < 0 ) $this->idx = 0;
    }
}
```

You'd then call your state machine like this:

```
$myStateMachine = new StateMachine( new TextReader($myXmlFileContents) );
$found = $myStateMachine->getTagContents("<some:tag>", "</some:tag>");
```

Comment: Seems to almost work, but it's not returning the content after then end of the tags: http://viper-7.com/yR7xND

Comment: @Petah It will read until it finds the end of the tag you're looking for.  Oh, I see, you want to allow other `<some:tag>`'s in your original tag.

Comment: I'll add something to do that.

Comment: @Petah I added another answer with a nested version.  It's not really a state machine, so I just added it as another answer  :)

Answer (score 0):

Ended up with this:

```
class TagExtractor {

    public $content;
    public $tag;

    public function getTagContent() {
        $result = [];
        $startTag = "<{$this->getTag()}>";
        $endTag = "</{$this->getTag()}>";
        $content = $this->getContent();
        $offset = strpos($content, $startTag);
        while ($offset !== false) {
            $end = $this->findEnd($content, $offset, $startTag, $endTag);
            $result[] = substr($content, $offset, $end - $offset);
            $offset = strpos($content, $startTag, $end);
        }
        return $result;
    }

    public function findEnd($content, $offset, $startTag, $endTag, $counter = 1) {
        $offset++;
        $nextStart = strpos($content, $startTag, $offset);
        $nextEnd = strpos($content, $endTag, $offset);
        if ($nextEnd === false) {
            $counter = 0;
        } elseif ($nextStart < $nextEnd && $nextStart !== false) {
            $counter++;
            $offset = $nextStart;
        } elseif ($nextEnd < $nextStart || ($nextStart === false && $nextEnd !== false)) {
            $counter--;
            $offset = $nextEnd;
        }
        if ($counter === 0) {
            return $offset + strlen($endTag);
        }
        return $this->findEnd($content, $offset, $startTag, $endTag, $counter);
    }

    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Getters and setters">
    public function getContent() {
        return $this->content;
    }

    public function setContent($content) {
        $this->content = $content;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getTag() {
        return $this->tag;
    }

    public function setTag($tag) {
        $this->tag = $tag;
        return $this;
    }
    // </editor-fold>
}
```